# Property googleCloudBuild is not allowed.yaml-schema: skaffold.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, skaffold

I implemented skaffold with google, but at the time of setting the "googleCloudBuild" property it throws this error => The googleCloudBuild property is not allowed. I tried changing the Skaffold version, but it doesn't work.
Attached image of the skaffold configuration

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt2l7.png)

I also consulted the official documentation of skaffold and google but I did not find anything relevant to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello! I was able to solve the problem, apparently it was a silly tab error, but that's how you learn. Thanks for the intention to help.

Comment: What do you mean by "silly tab error"? Do you mean you put the YAML entry at the wrong indentation level? Can you write an answer post? See [answer].

Comment: The real issue was probably with having both the "local" and "googleCloudBuild" properties, when you can only have one. In order to push changes to GCloud, you need to remove the "local" property from the skaffold.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the comments from `@user8773963` was correct.

It seems we can not have `skaffold` using local and cloud configured altogether.

Here is my example

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta4 #<==== On this version 
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: mfe-project-test
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: <Your imagename>/test
      context: test
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - dest: .
            src: "src/**/*.ts"
  #local:
    # concurrency: 1
    # tryImportMissing: false
    # useDockerCLI: false
    # push: false
  googleCloudBuild:          # It seems we can not have both configuration
    projectId: <Your project ID>
    region: <Your region>
manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - infra/k8s/*
```